# Identify a set of strings and remove them from a column

Tags: r, regex

I'm trying to loop through a column and remove any characters from the start of the row, that falls under my predefined set of strings.

**Reproducible Example**

```
df <- data.frame(serial = 1:3, name = c("Javier", "Kenneth", "Kasey"))

  serial    name
1      1  Javier
2      2 Kenneth
3      3   Kasey
```

**Condition Vector**
Removes these strings from the front of name only!

```
vec <- c("Ja", "Ka")
```

**Intended Output**

```
  serial    name
1      1    vier
2      2 Kenneth
3      3     sey
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We could create a pattern by pasting `vec` into one vector and remove their occurrence using `sub`.

```
df$name <- sub(paste0("^", vec, collapse = "|"), "", df$name)

df
#  serial    name
#1      1    vier
#2      2 Kenneth
#3      3     sey
```

---

In `stringr` we can also use `str_remove`

```
stringr::str_remove(df$name, paste0("^", vec, collapse = "|"))
#[1] "vier"    "Kenneth" "sey"
```

Comment: Hey @Ronak, does this remove the characters only at the start? For instance, it should not remove characters ("Ja") from "helloJavier"

Comment: @Javier Sorry, I missed that part. I have updated the answer so that it will remove the characters only from the start.

Answer (score 3):

Since we're using fixed length `vec` strings in this example, it might even be more efficient to use `substr` replacements. This will only really pay off in the case when `df` and/or `vec` is large though, and comes at the price of some flexibility.

```
df$name <- as.character(df$name)
sel <- substr(df$name, 1, 2) %in% vec
df$name[sel] <- substr(df$name, 3, nchar(df$name))[sel]

#  serial    name
#1      1    vier
#2      2 Kenneth
#3      3     sey
```

Answer (score 2):

We can also do this with `substring`

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
df$name <- substring(df$name, replace_na(str_locate(df$name, 
               paste(vec, collapse="|"))[,2] + 1, 1))
df$name
#[1] "vier"    "Kenneth" "sey"
```

---

Or with `str_replace`

```
str_replace(df$name, paste0("^", vec,  collapse="|"), "")
#[1] "vier"    "Kenneth" "sey"
```

---

Or using `gsubfn`

```
library(gsubfn)
gsubfn("^.{2}", setNames(rep(list(""), length(vec)), vec), as.character(df$name))
#[1] "vier"    "Kenneth" "sey"
```